# Symfony loading schema from old project

Tags: php, symfony

I created a symfony project in the same directory as another symfony project. This old project has a column type "phone_number" using another bundle. This project does not use that.

I've tried deleting composer.lock and vendor and composer installing. I've tried composer update (I was on lts). I've tried deleting cache both manually and via cli.

For some reason when I try to run app/console schema:update

```
  [Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]                                                
  Unknown column type "phone_number" requested. Any Doctrine type that you us  
  e has to be registered with \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::addType(). You can g  
  et a list of all the known types with \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::getTypesMa  
  p(). If this error occurs during database introspection then you might have  
  forgot to register all database types for a Doctrine Type. Use AbstractPla  
  tform#registerDoctrineTypeMapping() or have your custom types implement Typ  
  e#getMappedDatabaseTypes(). If the type name is empty you might have a prob  
  lem with the cache or forgot some mapping information.
```

my app/config/config.yml

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: photoProject
        connections:
            photoProject:
                driver: pdo_pgsql
                host: '%database_host%'
                port: '%database_port%'
                dbname: '%database_name%'
                user: '%database_user%'
                password: '%database_password%'
                charset: UTF8
                # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
                #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
                #     e.g. database_path: '%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db    3'
                #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
                #   3. Uncomment next line:
                #path: '%database_path%'

    orm:
        default_entity_manager: photoProject
        entity_managers:
            photoProject:
                connection: photoProject
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
                auto_mapping: true
                #auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'

doctrine_migrations:
    dir_name: "%kernel.root_dir%/app/DoctrineMigrations"
    namespace: Application\Migrations
    table_name: migration_versions
    name: Application Migrations
```

I've even deleted the old project and still getting the same error. I think this has to do with autloading some cached version of the old db schema, but I'm not sure where to find the problem.

Thanks!

---

```
{
"name": "root/photoproject",
"license": "proprietary",
"type": "project",
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "": "src/"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "app/AppKernel.php",
        "app/AppCache.php"
    ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "files": [
        "vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/VarDumper/Resources/functions/dump.php"
    ]
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.9",
    "doctrine/annotations": "^1.4",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
    "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^1.0",
    "doctrine/migrations": "^1.5",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
    "egulias/email-validator": "^2.1",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~4.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3,>=2.3.10",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.8.*",
    "twig/twig": "^1.0||^2.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "~3.0",
    "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "~2.7"
},
"scripts": {
    "symfony-scripts": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "@symfony-scripts"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "@symfony-scripts"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin",
    "sort-packages": true
},
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    },
    "branch-alias": null
}
```

}

Comment: can you try ``php bin/console do:ca:clear-metadata`` and after other console commands.

Comment: @MehmetSoylu
Okay it said,
Clearing ALL Metadata cache entries
Successfully deleted cache entries.


but still same error.

Comment: can you share your composer.json ? I think a bundle need a custom dcotrine type for database.

Comment: There are no extra bundles which one has phone_number field type. Probably your entities have a extra field type phone_number. It's mean you have to define phone number field for this entities in doctrine/dbal config.yml rows. But there is no clue for this field more. Here is a bundle definition sample https://github.com/misd-service-development/phone-number-bundle

Comment: yeah in my old project I was using https://github.com/misd-service-development/phone-number-bundle, which I'm not using in this one

Comment: probably your migrations or entities still have this field type.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. I had reused the exact same doctrine migration/db settings from an old project. I think there was a table named doctrine_migrations in my db and somehow when I was running anything it was erroring out.

Posting in case anyone else sees it. Look in your database and see if you have a table there with old migrations.